# Math.net data read in class method not assigned to class member

Tags: c#, math.net

I have a class library with objects using `Math.net`. The library contains classes that contain data and methods. As a trial I am instantiating an object of a member class and then call the the load method to fill the object with data from a file. However, the data loaded does not get passed to the new object. When I dump the object to the screen I get:

> EchoStateNet.EchoState+Input

Where I should get a data dump. Below the library with the class definition and a test calling it.

```
namespace EchoStateNet
{
    public class EchoState
    {
        // class that holds network input data
        public class Input
        {
            public Matrix<double> dataSet { get; set; }     // matrix holding train / test / run input data           

            public Input() : base() { }     // default constructor

            // method to load network data
            public void load(string filePath, string fileName)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataSet = DelimitedReader.Read<double>(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), false, ",", false);   // read the input data
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error loading data. Exception: " + ex);
                }
            }           

        }
```

And the part that calls this:

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EchoState.Input data = new EchoState.Input();

            data.load("..\\..", "MackeyGlass_t17.txt");

            Console.WriteLine("Input data:");
            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am getting suggests to me that I may not have instantiated an object properly, but the syntax of Math.net is a bit different than a typical `List<>` declaration, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect this to output?:

```
data.ToString()
```

Your `Input` class never overrides the `.ToString()` method, so the default implementation from `System.Object` is to output the class name.  Which is this:

> EchoStateNet.EchoState+Input

If you want to output something else, override the `.ToString()` method in your class.  Something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // return some string representation here
}
```

As for what a valid string representation of your object *should* be, that's up to you.  The only state your object holds is a `Matrix<double>`.  I'm not familiar with that type, so I don't know what one might expect it to look like.  But whatever you want it to look like, you'd format that in the `ToString()` method (using things like `StringBuilder` and/or `string.Format()` and return the resulting `string`.

Comment: this helps, so it's not the instantiation. The `ToString()` is implemented in the Math.net library for the `Matrix<>` class. So what I understand from this is that this implementation may not be accessible in this way.

Comment: @jdelange: If `Matrix<T>` has a `ToString()` already then all you'd need to do in your method is: `return dataSet.ToString();`

Comment: Excellent! This indeed outputs the contents of `dataSet`. So now I can add other data types and methods in the same manner.